# How to map two different length lists in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists.

Say,

```
letterList = [(1, 'a') (1, 'b')]
bigramList = [(2, 'ab'), (2, 'cd'), (2, 'ef')]
```

I would like to map the two lists together to get this output:

```
print(myMap)
# [ ((1, a), (2, ab)), ((1, b), (2, cd)), (None, (2, ef)) ]
```

I am getting an output of something like this: `<map object at 0x7f639461efd0>`

I know my problem lies in this line:

```
myMap = (map(None, letterList, biGramList))
```

I think it's because of Python 3. Just not too sure how to fix it and get the output I want.

Comment: "... how to fix it and get the output I want" - it would be helpful if you showed us what is the output you want. and also an example of input...

Comment: If you know the problem is in `myMap = (map(None, letterList, biGramList))`, then post the sample values of `letterList` and `biGramList` and do _not_ post everything else. we are not interested in seeing the irrelevant code.

Comment: Input example:
google
Both
Output: As the Format displays...
[ ((LetterFreq1,Letter1), (BiGramFreq1,BiGram1)), ((LetterFreq2,Letter2), (BiGramFreq2,BiGram2)), (( , ), ( , )) etc... ]

Comment: Further, please remove all the irrelevant code (~95% of the code you posted) and provide a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `map(None, ...)`? Man, that's an old idiom. Pre-Python 2, even! `zip` has been a better way to express that since 2.0, and `list(zip(...))` if you need a list on Python 3.

Comment: The way you declared `letterList` and `bigramList` - this code will not run! Did you mean something like: `letterList = [(1, "a") (1, "b")]` ?

Comment: @alfasin That was the example. My code declares the list like this:     letterList = [(v,k) for k,v in letterDict.items() ]

Comment: @user2357112 thanks but that only works when the lists are the same length. It ignores the rest of the elements in my longer list. Hence why I wanted the None in there

Comment: @John try to run things before you post them, what you posted was: `letterList = [(1, a) (1, b)]` - this code will fail because of 2 reasons: 1. the strings are not quoted. 2. you forgot the comma between the tuples.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
>>> letterList = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
>>> bigramList = [(2, 'ab'), (2, 'cd'), (2, 'ef')]
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(letterList, bigramList))
[((1, 'a'), (2, 'ab')), ((1, 'b'), (2, 'cd')), (None, (2, 'ef'))]
```

Note that you don't necessarily need to coerce it to a list to use it, it's just convenient for printing.

Comment: I'm not allowed to import anything besides regular expressions for this exercise.

Comment: @John The first law of programming is: ignore all improper restrictions, because your bosses are always going to be dumber than you.

Comment: @o11c The first law of taking a programming course: do not ignore the restrictions imposed by your professor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to import external modules, then this may help:

```
result = list(zip(letterList,bigramList))
l1 = len(letterList)
l2 = len(bigramList)
if l1 > l2:
    result += [(item, None) for item in letterList[l2:]]
else:
    result += [(None, item) for item in bigramList[l1:]]
#[((1, 'a'), (2, 'ab')), ((1, 'b'), (2, 'cd')), (None, (2, 'ef'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

inline `if else` could work - but this relies on knowing the shorter list from the start

```
lst = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
bst = [(2, 'ab'), (2, 'cd'), (2, 'ef')]

[(lst[i] if i < len(lst) else None,
  bst[i])
 for i in range(len(bst))]

Out[30]: [((1, 'a'), (2, 'ab')), ((1, 'b'), (2, 'cd')), (None, (2, 'ef'))]
```

actually a 'one-liner' list comprehension but with line breaks in hope of improving readability

**edit:** it can be generalized to treat the inputs symmetrically

```
[(lst[i] if i < len(lst) else None,
  bst[i] if i < len(bst) else None)
 for i in range(max(len(lst), len(bst)))]
```